# how to delete the partition after mkfs

Tags: linux, filesystems, redhat-enterprise-linux, ext

we created the ext file system on new sdd disk as the follwing

```
 mkfs.ext4  -j -m 0 /dev/sdd -F
```

in order to get the disk as was before mkfs

I guess we need to delete the partition that created by mkfs ,

how to perform that ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1281326/opposite-of-the-mkfs-ext4-command

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You're right, but since there is my answer here (I didn't notice the duplicate before) and no answer there (yet), maybe it's better to mark the other question as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`mkfs` doesn't create a partition, it creates a filesystem. You created a filesystem on the entire device `/dev/sdd` (as opposed to a partition e.g. `/dev/sdd1`).

Your disk is not partitioned, the resulting layout is called superfloppy. If you want to utilize (almost) the whole device to a single filesystem then it's still better to have a partition table with one partition. Compare: [*Uses of single-partition disk configuration*](https://superuser.com/q/1181320/432690).

Tools like `fdisk` or `gdisk` should allow you to create a partition table without any preparations (you will lose data from the current filesystem though, so copy what you want to save). If you create a single partition then you should later run `mkfs.ext4` with `/dev/sdd1` as a target to create a filesystem on the partition.

If you want to wipe the current filesystem (prior to `fdisk`/`gdisk`/whatever or for any other reason) then

- fill the beginning of the disk with zeros, 1MB should be enough:

  ```
    dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=1M count=1
  ```
- or use [`wipefs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/wipefs) on `/dev/sdd`; this tool is designed to erase filesystems.