# How to fix fdisk wrong partitions

Tags: usb, partitioning, linux-mint, fdisk

I'm running dual boot of Linux Mint 19.2 Tina and Windows 10.

I wanted to format my usb flash drive but when I open it with `fdisk /dev/sdc` and then type p i get shown partitions of my computer file system.

```
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x73736572

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1       1920221984 3736432267 1816210284   866G 72 unknown
/dev/sdc2       1936028192 3889681299 1953653108 931,6G 6c unknown
/dev/sdc3                0          0          0     0B  0 Empty
/dev/sdc4         27722122   27722568        447 223,5K  0 Empty

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

This is output of df command so you see the flash is mounted on /mnt/flash :

```
udev             4013084        0   4013084   0% /dev
tmpfs             808924     1456    807468   1% /run
/dev/sda3       20520784 16696288   2759024  86% /
tmpfs            4044608   131512   3913096   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            4044608        0   4044608   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0         93440    93440         0 100% /snap/vectr/2
/dev/loop2         56320    56320         0 100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/loop1         99328    99328         0 100% /snap/core/9665
/dev/loop7        145152   145152         0 100% /snap/code/39
/dev/loop3        297984   297984         0 100% /snap/vlc/1620
/dev/loop4        297472   297472         0 100% /snap/vlc/1700
/dev/loop6        147840   147840         0 100% /snap/code/38
/dev/sdb3         101590    31572     70018  32% /boot/efi
/dev/sda5      383271464 12161596 351571080   4% /home
tmpfs             808920       72    808848   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop9         56704    56704         0 100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/loop8         98944    98944         0 100% /snap/core/9804
/dev/sdc         3914748    14784   3899964   1% /mnt/flash
```

So how do I fix it to show me partitions of my flash drive?

Comment: Related topics: [filesystem on entire device](https://superuser.com/a/1281363/432690); and [why to avoid such setup](https://superuser.com/a/1181406/432690).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your flash drive currently does not have partitions. Whatever version of `fdisk` you’re using is trying to interpret the start of the filesystem as a partition table (MBR).

You have two options: Continue partition-less (with `mkfs.whatever /dev/sdc`) or create partitions.

To create partitions, simply enter `o` in `fdisk` to create a new empty MBR partition table. You can then create partitions as usual/desired and format them.

Answer (score 0):

So I had no partitions at all? Strange... Anyway I fixed it by using gParted. Formated first to clear and then I made 1 partiton as fat32. Thank you for your answer!