# How to use Linux to Partition and Format a blank external hard drive where the partitions were lost

Tags: linux, formatting, partition-recovery, command-line-arguments

I need some help rescuing a new and blank 4 terabyte external SSD USB hard drive.

The original partitions were 3.64T and a 0.36 partition labeled "Microsoft Partition"

Using GParted, I accidentally lost both of those partitions.

I tried using GParted to make a fresh partition table.  GParted ran over night and never finished.  The next morning "process in progress" was still listed there.   I saw several error messages flash by saying my "computer was full".  Huh? I was working on a blank 4T external drive.

As of now, when I plug the 4T drive in Mint Linux does not mount it.

It also does not appear when running df -h ( before I messed things up it appeared as /dev/sdb2).

I would for the drive to be recognized by Linux again, have one large partition ( I want to copy multiple hard drive images to it ), and be formatted in ext4.

Is there a way to do this and have some kind of progress indicator running since it is such a large drive?   I would like to know that things are working and I would like to be able to retrieve error messages.

Given that, how would I do this via the command line?

Comment: It's normal for it to not be mounted if it's not partitioned. Writing a partition table should be super quick though since it just writes the table...

Comment: df -h does not detect it.   How can I partition it via a command line tool if I don't have a path to point it to?

Comment: `df -h` only shows filesystems. Until you create a partition and format it, you don't have a filesystem. Try `lsblk` which shows disks and partitions.

Comment: In short: `wipefs` (just in case, probably not needed), `fdisk` (or `gdisk`), `mkfs.ext4` ([why so many tools?](https://superuser.com/a/1281363/432690)). Can you take it from here? (`man` is your friend). I understand you want to create everything anew, i.e. discard the old data whatever it is. What a great opportunity to experiment! There are only two scenarios where things get worse: (1) you confuse disks (e.g. `/dev/sda` instead of `/dev/sdb`; `lsblk` is also your friend; think twice twice); (2) random malfunction of the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kamil Maciorowski's comment I got enough clues to find this tutorial that exactly fit what I was trying to do

https://linuxize.com/post/fdisk-command-in-linux/